# Updating data with Highcharts alters initial set

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am drawing a chart using Highcharts, with my data passed to javascript as data attribute, and this works perfectly fine.

I want to be able to change the data, what I am doing like that :

```
chart.highcharts().series[0].setData(chart.data().secondset, true);
```

chart being properly defined, this works fine as well.

Then, if I try to go back to my initial data using the exact same code :

```
chart.highcharts().series[0].setData(chart.data().firstset, true);
```

it does not work, and it seems like my initial data has disappeared, so Highcharts would alter my initial data.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8zwL0cv3/1/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you noticed the Y values getting changed on Button Click?? Is that intentional or a bug?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you exactly mean, could you please explain?

Comment: If you notice the Chart carefully, On load y axis values are 0,2,4,6,8 and On button click it changes to 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing that the firstset changed the format I changed

```
chart.data().firstset
```

to

```
eval(chart.attr('data-secondset'))
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/baqowskg/)

Comment: Have noticed the change in Y scale??

Comment: yes I did, thats why I changed the way the data was retrieved

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $.extend to create a copy of data. In your case you use references, so first value is incorrect.

```
$.extend([],chart.data().firstset)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8zwL0cv3/2/